# WordPress is_tags not detecting tag clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a simple if statement that should show something different depending if tag, archive or something else.

they all work apart from is_tag, for some reason when I click on a tag it shows the archive condition.
I have tried multiple solutions and look around the internet, nothing seems to work..

Am i doing something wrong ?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
            <?php
            $current_tag = single_tag_title("", false);
            $archive_year = get_the_time('Y');
            if (is_archive()) {
                ?>
                <h1 class="pt-2"><?php echo 'Archive ', $archive_year?></h1>
                <?php
            } elseif (is_tag()) {
               ?>
                <h1>tag working <?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p>Tag: <?php single_tag_title(); ?></p>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

one again, my aim when I load this template from clicking on a tag I was for the statement the tag statement to run.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_archive()` is very general, and will return true for category, tag, author, date, custom post type, and custom taxonomy based archives - which is why it's catching your tag pages

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/

You might instead try using `is_post_type_archive()` which applies specifically to post type archive pages.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/

OR simply reverse your conditions - test for `is_tag()` first, then `is_archive()` second.